# Bold and non bold f are different characters in math

Tags: math-fonts

In an equation I want to write force vector with boldface f and its components in normal font. The result of this code

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{f} \neq f
\end{equation}
```

is unacceptable:

[image]

Any suggestions, apart from switching to a different character?

Comment: use the bm package and use `\bm` instead of `\mathbf`

Comment: You only say what is unacceptable. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: @mickep - Unless I'm badly mistaken, the OP wants the bold "f" glyph to mimic the shape of the non-bold "f" glyph -- italic/slanted with a long "lower tail".

Comment: I did not see bm in the texlive lsiting. How do I get it?

Comment: @Mico Or vice versa. They should be clearly the same symbol.

Comment: @my2cts - You wrote, "I did not see bm in the texlive [listing]. How do I get it?"How about by typing `\usepackage{bm}` (as is also demonstrated in my answer). FWIW, I use TeXLive2023.

Comment: @my2cts - If you don't like the output generated by `\mathbf` (or its Plain-TeX variant, `$\bf f$`) please take up your grievance with Don Knuth, the creator of the TeX system. This setting has been around for 40+ years...

Answer (score 6):

By design, `\mathbf` generates upright bold glyphs. As @daleif has already pointed out in comment, you should use `\bm` (a macro provided by the [bm](https://ctan.org/pkg/bm) package) to generate *slanted* ("italic") bold glyphs in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{f} \quad \bm{f} \quad f$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a compilation in `lualatex` and the package `unicode-math`

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\symbfit{f} \quad f$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unicode-math` (with LuaLaTeX) with the `math-style=ISO` option to avoid many of the "unacceptable" inconsistencies in traditional TeX math typesetting. This will also give you italic capital Greek letters.

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  math-style=ISO,
  ]{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\vec\symbf
}

\begin{document}

\[
  f \vec{f}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]